# Session Invalid when using AJP

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat, mod-proxy-ajp

I have the following setup:
Apache running the front end (AngularJS)
Tomcat 7 Running back end (Spring MVC, Spring Security)

#### Apache Config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_ajp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ajp.so

    ProxyRequests     off
    ProxyPreserveHost on

    ProxyPass         /api/  ajp://132.230.166.21:8009/OntoRais/api/
    ProxyPassReverse  /api/  ajp://132.230.166.21:8009/OntoRais/api/

    Alias /rais "/home/bwright/Repositories/ontology-toolchain/WebClient"
    <Directory "/home/bwright/Repositories/ontology-toolchain/WebClient">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory
</VirtualHost>
```

As one can see I pass all api calls to the tomcat server using the ajp protocol.

#### Tomcat Config (Server.xml)

Nothing changed from clean install apart from:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"  enableLookups="false"/>
```

Now when I try to access a tomcat resource via the front end I get 403

```
HTTP Status 403 - Full authentication is required to access this resource accessing /OntoRais/api/user
```

In the tomcat server log I get

```
13:25:10.034 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.SessionManagementFilter - Requested session ID ED0779DC647DEE3C58DEA7059C260594 is invalid.
```

When accessing the same resource via the bowser directly to the tomcat server
`http://localhost:8080/OntoRais/api/user` everything works fine.

#### Edit

To clarify, 132.230.166.21 is the same machine as localhost. I changed the configuration to say localhost without any change.

Hope someone here can help me out with this
thanks
Benedict

Comment: try testing with "132.230.166.21:8009" not localhost, since you didn't configure Apache for the same thing you are testing "successfully"

Comment: Hmm how would I go about that. When trying using the browser I get ```Connection Reset ```

Comment: So basically you have a networking issue when not connecting locally.

Comment: hmm I should point out that "132.230.166.21" is the same machine as localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was with setting the SESSIONID after adding

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /OntoRais /
```

to the apache settings, all worked.